# How to read the Current SharePoint library name that user is working on?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the Projects I am working on, I have a requirement to read the current Sharepoint library name using JSOM (should be dynamic in nature). I have to show it in a web part so if someone knows how to achieve that via JSOM approach, please help me with the line of code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following scripts to get the title of the current list/library that the user is working on:

```
function getListName(){
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.core.js", "SP.ListOperation.Selection",
        function () {   
           var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
           console.log(listId);     
           if (typeof (listId) == "undefined" || listId == null || listId == "") {
               return;
           }
           var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
           var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
           ctx.load(list);
           ctx.executeQueryAsync(
               Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                   console.log("current list/library name: "+list.get_title());
                   alert(list.get_title());
               }),
               Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                   console.log(args.get_message());
               })
           );
       });
  });
}
```

Refer to: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2016/08/get-title-of-current-list-in-sharepoint.html